# Crazy problem when comparing NSInteger to int

Tags: iphone, nsinteger

I have a crazy problem when comparing an NSInteger to int, as follows:

```
NSInteger count = [dictionary count];

if (count == 0) {
    // Do something
}
else {
    // Do something
}
```

When the count is zero, the snipped code in the if clause is run, but when the count number is changed, the snipped code in the if clause is not run (this is correct), but the snipped code in the else clause is not run either. When I debug, the cursor always jumps over the else clause.

I tried to change count number to int or compare it as an NSNumber, but nothing changed.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you are recompiling your project properly when you modified your source code? You might be accidentally running the old source which would cause the xcode debugger to skip any added lines. NSInteger is just an alias for a int (or maybe int64?) type.
Try adding a print statement NSLog("count = %d", count);

Comment: I already use command + shift + K to clear cache then re-build project, I tried to debug this code many times, the count is changed, poor me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing related to NSInteger and int here. The logic of if else is that exactly one of them has to be called, no matter what happens. So, if none of them is called, something else happened wrongly. Can you just NSLog both of the if and else clause. It is also better if you show me what is inside if and else clause

Comment: Oh my god, after I restart my computer, this problem is gone :(

Comment: that's funny. Maybe something wrong with your XCode:), did you try to relaunch it

Comment: I did restart X-Code but there was nothing change until restart computer, maybe I need to re-install my X-Code :(